# onclick Search - jump to search results section

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I would like to change the functionality of WP Casa theme Paraiba. http://wpcasa.com/demo/paraiba/

Right now the search results are displayed under the page fold - my aim is to scroll down on them after the search button is clicked.
Would you advise me how to accomplish that?

Thanks.

Comment: You should share your codes that generates the error or you stuck with-in, instead of provideing the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    $(document).on('click','.listing-search-submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#main-wrap").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
```

**NOTE** : This answer depends on the link given by you.So if you have made changes to class or ID then above code won't run.

Comment: Make sure you have added jQuery to it.